States that verify behaviour of Pauli operators in Clifford circuits
I have a circuit composed of Clifford gates and Pauli-basis measurements. I am also told that a set of Pauli operators $P = \{ P_1, P_2, ..., P_n\}$ commute with the circuit. When I say that $P_i$ commutes with the gates, that is clear. When I say it commutes with measurements, I mean that the post-measurement state statistics are the same whether I apply $P_i$ and then do the measurement or do the measurement and then apply $P_i$ to the post-measurement state.
I would like to programmatically verify this claim that the circuit commutes with all the elements of $P$.
Can I do this by checking that certain stabilizer states behave like eigenstates of the circuit? That is, I want to send in some stabilizer states $\Psi = \{\psi_1, \psi_2,... \}$, confirm that the circuit leaves them unchanged and use this to validate that all elements of $P$ commute with the circuit. If yes, given $P$, how should I choose the elements of $\Psi$?

How have you programmed your circuit?

I have not done it yet. I know that I can use a stabilizer tableau and check that it is the same tableau after the circuit. I am just wondering if this can also equivalently be expressed in terms of states e.g. if it is claimed that $X\otimes I \rightarrow X\otimes I$, what states does one need to check at input and output of the circuit before certifying that $X\otimes I \rightarrow X\otimes I$?

I would have thought it would be easier to do it directly with the tableau.


I would like to programmatically verify this claim that the circuit commutes with all the elements of P
.

You want stim.Circuit.has_flow.
import stim

circuit = stim.Circuit(...)
pauli = stim.PauliString(...)
flow = stim.Flow(input=pauli, output=pauli)

assert circuit.has_flow(flow)


Can I do this by checking that certain stabilizer states behave like eigenstates of the circuit?

It's sufficient to try random states. For example, the flow test from arXiv:2302.02192 works as follows: prepare a maximally mixed state and a $|+\rangle$ ancilla, phase-kickback the start pauli string onto the ancilla, perform the circuit, phase-kickback the end pauli string onto the ancilla, then verify the ancilla ended up in the $|+\rangle$ state. For correct flows this always passes. For incorrect flows it will fail at least 25% of the time (if the circuit is a stabilizer circuit). You can then turn that 25% into 99.99999999999% by repeating 100 times.

To get a deterministic answer, instead of a probabilistic answer, you would track the starting Pauli string across the circuit (stim.PauliString.after) and confirm it ended up equal to the end Pauli string. The main caveat is that the end Pauli string may actually be equal to the start Pauli string (propagated through the circuit) times a stabilizer prepared by reset gates during the circuit. To account for this case you must do Gaussian elimination over generators of the prepared stabilizers and see if there is any combination of reset stabilizers times input stabilizer that produce the output stabilizer.

Does has_flow essentially check the stabilizer tableau including the Gaussian elimination step? That is, it takes all the stabilizer generators of the code + one logical operator e.g. $X_1$ and checks that the tableau after the circuit has $X_1$ as a generator?

@Paulo The algorithm it uses isn't set it stone. Currently, for signed flow checks, it uses a variant of the randomized test. For unsigned flow checks it does a deterministic test that avoids needing the tableau simulation, the Gaussian elimination, or the random sampling.
